# ConnectionClosedError: Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL:

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, boto, amazon-sagemaker

So I'm trying to figure out Sagemaker and can get an endpoint for a tensorflow model up and running. Strangely enough, when I send small images to it, up to 220x220 (40kb), it runs just fine! However I get a connection closed error when I try anything larger, say 225x225.

I've tried from different networks and computers and get the same error. Also, I don't think I'm anywhere near the 5MB limit for sagemaker requests so I must admit I'm stumped on this one. Anyone happen to know what might be the cause of this? Thanks for your help. 
I'm calling my model via boto as follows:

```
config = Config(connect_timeout=999999, read_timeout=9999999)
client = boto3.client("runtime.sagemaker", config=config)
data = {"instances": [{"x":x, "x2":x2}]}
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName='dcscn', 
                                Body=json.dumps(data),
                                ContentType="application/json")

response_body = response['Body']
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 125, in _send_request
    method, url, body, headers, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 152, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 236, in send
    return super(AWSConnection, self).send(str)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 975, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 944, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 642, in write
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 258, in send
    decode_content=False,
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 343, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 125, in _send_request
    method, url, body, headers, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 152, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 236, in send
    return super(AWSConnection, self).send(str)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 975, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 944, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
  File "/Users/bhhj/anaconda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 642, in write
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ping_endpoint.py", line 100, in <module>
    ContentType="application/json")
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 667, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 137, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 231, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 244, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/Users/bhhj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 289, in send
    endpoint_url=request.url
botocore.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL:
```

Comment: Did you try with a smaller image? Like 150x150? It’s not clear if you can only run 220x220 or if you run until 220x220?

Comment: Smaller images, up to 220x220 run just fine. Thanks for the clarifying question

Comment: Inferences have a hard timeout of 60 seconds (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html). How long is your request taking? The error says something I would expect from a read timeout (aka your model not responding fast enough)

Comment: The error comes back after about 7-8 seconds, so I'm not sure it'd be hitting the 60 second limit.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Looks like this issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3999

Answer (score 8):

It can be a network error.
If you are connected to a VPN , try after disconnecting it
try with better internet connection
my case, closing the VPN worked

Comment: I haven't looked into this issue too deeply, but disconnecting from VPN was able to fix it for me. Thanks!

Comment: This was correct answer for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a firewall issue. How to troubleshoot: first, to do the same thing with aws cli and --debug flag. Already, with debug, you may see something. Then note the url and then try to ping the machine, in my case I had:

```
ping api.sagemaker.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
33 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 800ms.
```

Whitelisting the url solved the issue